# Excel delays caused by INDEX

Tags: excel, indexing, tabs, excel-formula, rows

I have 1 main tab and 10 other tabs that use the INDEX function to get data from main tab for their needs. Every time I edit the document, no matter what I type in any cell, (it could just be strings or numbers), it lags, or delays processing and on the top I see an "Excel not responding" alert for a good 5-10 seconds before it completes the task. I tried speaking with Microsoft support but they have no idea whats causing it. Any thought?

What I did:

Say I have three categories for FOOD: Snacks, Lunch, Dinner.
Then I have 4 tabs: Main tab is FOOD, then 3 more tabs: Snacks, Lunch, Dinner.
Then For the three tabs that get data from a table in "FOOD" tab, I use the following formula to filter and post data by their criteria:

```
=IF(ROWS(C$7:C27)>$E$1,"",INDEX('FOOD'!C$2:C$500,SMALL(IF('FOOD'!TABLE2=$B$1,ROW('FOOD'!TABLE2)-ROW('GL Details'!$A$2)+1),ROWS(C$2:C22))))
```

Is this complex enough a formula to cause delays and freeze ups?

Comment: Looks like an array formula. You are correct that it's a complex formula. The easiest way to make it faster is to create a formula that does not use arrays.

Comment: Would turning off automatic calculation, doing your edits, then re-enabling automatic calculation work or just setting calculation to manual and forcing the re-calc as necessary work? You could do all the edits then go for coffee...

Comment: the easiest way is to use excel online xD i got similar problem but I copied content from word to excel and it was freezing